# A variant of Bertrand ballot theorem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to solve this variant of Bertrand ballot theorem.

For my description I am adopting all the notations from this [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_ballot_theorem) source.

The original problem is to find the probability that the first candidate is always strictly ahead in the vote count. Consider now the problem to find the probability that the second candidate is never ahead (i.e. ties are allowed); the solution is

$$ \frac{p+1-q}{p+1} $$

where, $p$ is number of voters of A and $q$ is number of voters of B.

Now, I am trying one particular method and coming up with answer different than this. I need help in understanding what mistake I am making.

My arguments are:

I use notation of AAABB.. for representing a voting sequence.

1) The number of cases when A starts and strictly loses for some prefix of the vote sequence is equal to number of vote sequence that start with "BB".

The idea is since A starts and loses at some prefix. Consider first such prefix for this particular sequence. Now we reverse this particular prefix. We will get a vote sequence starting with "BB". On the other side Whenever I take a sequence starting "BB" it will always have a prefix for which (#B - #a) = 1, Since at the end #A > #B. We will take first such prefix. The prefix must be ending with "A". So we can reverse it and get a vote sequence starting with "A" where A loses for some prefix.

2) Now, I use this to calculate probability that A will not lose for some prefix.
It is equal to probability that A starts minus probability that there is prefix for which A loses. 
$$   = \frac{p}{p+q} - \frac{q(q-1)}{(p+q-1)(p+q)}  $$

It does not match with the answer given on Wikipedia.
It was little difficult to write my problem. If it is still ambiguous then please suggest edit it to make it better.

Comment: You just have to add a fictional vote for $A$ at the very beginning of the vote count, then remove it at the end.

Comment: Can you also help in finding out mistake in my method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your following statement has some issues.

```
So we can reverse it and get a vote sequence starting with "A" where A loses for some prefix.
```

Unlike original problem where number of A and B are equal, in this case on reversing the string we will not get a unique prefix.

```
ABB BAAA
ABABB AA
```

Both the above strings on reversing the firs part give same string

```
BBABAAA
```

The argument regarding one to one correspondence holds only for #(A) = #(B)